# How to find undesired output in Laravel/PHP

Tags: php, laravel, echo

I have faced an annoying issue, so in only validation error output, only hard-coded number (2) is being printed at the beginning of JSON response.

```
2{
"message": "The password field is required.",
"errors": {
    "password": [
        "The password field is required."
    ]
}
```

}

I guess it is not related to the vendor folder because I already deleted the vendor folder and reinstalled composer dependencies.

I assume it's something `echo` command that causes this problem. But I can't find where it's. Can someone help me with troubleshooting?

Additionally, I tired another way to validate using Validator facade. It's same.

```
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'first_name' => 'required|string',
        'last_name' => 'required|string',
        'email' => 'required|string|unique:users,email',
        'mobile' => ['required', 'string', 'unique:users,mobile', new AzeMobile()],
        'password' => 'required|string|confirmed'
    ]);

    dd($validator->fails());
```

output:

[image]

Comment: If it is return 2 only with specific route returning validation? If yes, need to look your Http/Request class or code where you defined validation rules.

Comment: It will great! if you can provide more context with code.

Comment: @sssurii you mean Illuminate\Http\Request file? But it comes with a vendor package. I have reinstalled composer dependencies. It shouldn't have an issue.

Comment: If at the very begining of your method and before you perform the validation you do `dd('foobar');`, do you still see the `2` output? Do you have any middleware or custom Form Requests?

Comment: It was inside `lang/en/validation.php`. I posted the answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After debugging, I figured out the problem was inside `lang/en/validation.php`

[image: validation.php]